# Limit of $(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the limit of the sequence $(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^n$?

Let $a_n:=(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^n$ then $\ \ln \ a_n=n\ \ln(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$

$\implies \lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln\ a_n=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\ \ln(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$

$\implies \ln \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}{\frac{1}{n}}$

$\implies \ln \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{ln2}{2^n(1-2^n)}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}  [\frac{0}{0} \ \ \text{form}]$

I am stuck here, what should I do after this?

Comment: Can I modify the inequality $ln(1+x) \leq x$ for all $x \geq 0,$ and use it here to get a bound for $ln(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$?

Comment: Using Bernoulli's Inequality we have $$1-\frac{n}{2^n}\le \left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)^n\le \frac1{1+\frac{n}{2^n}}$$Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing where you left:
$$  \frac{ \frac{\ln2}{2^n (1 -2^n)}  }{\frac{-1}{n^2}} = - \frac{n^2 \ln2}{2^n(1-2^n)} = \frac{n^2 \ln2}{2^n(2^n - 1)}$$

It's pretty obvious / not hard to prove that this tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity ("exponent beats polynomial") and so your limit should go to $e^0 = 1$

Another approach is to "fix" the exponent so it would suit the limit of $e$:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n})^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}( \overbrace{(1 + \frac{-1}{2^n})^{2^n}}^{\text{1/e}})^{ \overbrace{\frac{n}{2^n}}^{\text{Tends to 0}}}$$

Comment: @Saikat We didn't actually change the power, if you use power rules we get back: $ (a^{2^n})^{ \frac{n}{2^n}} = a^{2^n \cdot \frac{n}{2^n}} = a^n$

Comment: I got it. I could not see it, because of the overbraces. Thank you.

Comment: Using Bernoulli's Inequality we have $$1-\frac{n}{2^n}\le \left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)^n\le \frac1{1+\frac{n}{2^n}}$$Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$(1-1/n)^n \to 1/e
$,
$(1-1/2^n)^{2^n}
\to 1/e
$,
so
$(1-1/2^n)^n
=((1-1/2^n)^{2^n})^{n/2^n}
\to (1/e)^{n/2^n}
\to 1
$
since $n/2^n \to 0$.